# Counting how many data that exist [SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, count, row

im not sure about this question is already asked by anyone else or not yet because this is actually easy but my head is just still can't see the way out of this problem. 

this is just like how many times that we do sampling at the material.

```
SELECT
  TABLE01.MATERIAL_NO,
  TABLE01.Sample_Tempt1,
  TABLE01.Sample_Tempt2,
  TABLE01.Sample_Tempt3,
  TABLE01.Sample_Tempt4,
  TABLE01.Sample_Tempt5
FROM
  TABLE01
```

is it possible to create another column to show count of sample_tempt times?
i mean, if the tempt1 tempt2 data are exist, the column shows 2, when tempt2, tempt4 and tempt5 data are exist, the column show 3. and so on.
Thank you for helping me ^^ 
Sample :

```
Material no | Sample_Tempt1 | Sample_Tempt2 | Sample_Tempt3 | Sample_Tempt4 | Sample_Tempt5 | 
PO1025           120            150                               102                        
PO1026                          122
```

For the PO1025, i want to create new column that generate "3" because the sample data that exist is only 3, for the PO1026 i want it generate "1" since the sample data that exist is only "1". quite simple right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hey dude, can you give me a page or any tutorial to edit my sql code format to be like just what you did?

Comment: ah sorry for the ambiguous sentences there, i mean the data is not exist, not the attribute.

Comment: When you edit your question, click on the question mark in the upper right corner of the textbox.

Comment: ah i see, to make the code with that grey background, we have to follow the "Code and Preformatted Text" Section, right?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: i can, but i still don't know how to build table here, so get ready to edit my question. hehe sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If "by exist" you mean "value is not `NULL`", then you can count the number of non-NULL values in each row as:

```
SELECT t1.MATERIAL_NO,
       t1.Sample_Tempt1, t1.Sample_Tempt2, t1.Sample_Tempt3, t1.Sample_Tempt4, t1.Sample_Tempt5,
       ((case when t1.sample_temp1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.sample_temp2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.sample_temp3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.sample_temp4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.sample_temp5 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NumTempts
FROM TABLE01 t1;
```

Note that I introduced a table alias.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: it said "invalid relational operator". hmm sorry, i don't know which part is invalid.

Comment: @EkynaldiEky . . . I hate when I do that.  I left out that all important `is not null`.  Arrg.  I just fixed.

Comment: whoaa it prefectly works, so much thanks dude, i learn a lot here. this is great haha thank you thank you.